# Bazel pip_parse results in repository not defined

Tags: bazel, bazel-python

Trying to build a set up Python package dependencies with `rules_python` per [these instructions](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python#installing-third_party-packages) but when running `bazel build` I get this error:

```
ERROR: error loading package under directory '':
error loading package 'zzz':
Unable to find package for @my_deps//:requirements.bzl:
The repository '@my_deps' could not be resolved:
Repository '@my_deps' is not defined.
```

`WORKSPACE` file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

rules_python_version = "740825b7f74930c62f44af95c9a4c1bd428d2c53" # Latest @ 2021-06-23
http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    sha256 = "3474c5815da4cb003ff22811a36a11894927eda1c2e64bf2dac63e914bfdf30f",
    strip_prefix = "rules_python-{}".format(rules_python_version),
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/archive/{}.zip".format(rules_python_version),
)
```

and the `BUILD` file:

```
load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_parse")

pip_parse(
   name = "my_deps",
   requirements_lock = "requirements.txt",
)
load("@my_deps//:requirements.bzl", "install_deps", "requirement")
install_deps()
```

Is `pip_parse` responsible for creating the repository `@my_deps`? If so, why can't it be found by `load`?

If it matters, this is on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip_parse` should go into the `WORKSPACE` file, not the `BUILD` file.

If you put it in the `BUILD` file by mistake, you might get this error.

Hopefully this helps a future searcher who might make the same mistake.

Comment: But what if you really have to call pip_parse on various requirement.txts present in various python project folders , how can we load a specific .bzl with a function like req_parse() which in turn will call pip_parse and appropriate install_deps() ?

Comment: I'm a Bazel newbie, but my project does have multiple sub-packages with their own requirements.txt files and I just put them all in my workspace. The sequence of `pip_parse`, `load`, and `install_deps` is just repeated for the different sub-packages.

Comment: thanks for the reply, wondering what the design pattern would look like if I cannot put all these various python apps with their individual requriement.txt at the top workspace file and instead have only one entry point in WORKSPACE file for python projects so that I can deal with my reqs internally in .bzl files and functions.